# How does Grails spring security rememberMe on custom auth?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0, grails-plugin

I use grails spring security with a custom auth method for facebook authentication:

```
def auth() {
    ...
}
```

When I check the cookie in my browser I can see that the cookie lifetime is finished when the browser session is closed. The persistent rememberMe cookie is set only if I use the default login/auth action from the plugin.

What do I have to change such that the user which is loggedin with my custom auth method is not logged out between sessions?

For reauthentication I use:

```
def success() {

    // get facebook user data

    springSecurityService.reauthenticate username

    if(springSecurityService.loggedIn) {
            // do something

    }
}
```

How do I set the rememberMe cookie?

Comment: I think the configuration is fine. Maybe it's because you set up your browser cookie preference as "keep until" you quit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea: let the spring security remember me service know it should consider the successful login.

1. In your facebook success action, upon successful authentication, do the following:

   ```
   //wire remember me services
   def rememberMeServices

   //... in your action:
   springSecurityService.reauthenticate username

   def authentication = SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication
   rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, authentication)
   ```
2. in your Config.groovy, add the following

   ```
   grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.alwaysRemember = true
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the request's POST parameter between a submit of your original auth.gsp and your custom's auth.gsp. There will be an additional hidden field, which is missing. Use Firebug for this.

Comment: I see that in the original auth POST there is a grails_remember_me cookie being set. But how can I modify my auth method such that this is also included? There is a POST to http://myurl.com/j_spring_security_check with the parameter:
_spring_security_remember_me=on
j_password=user
j_username=password

How do I have to modify my auth method to set this cookie?

Comment: how to you authenticate after that? you should just post to the j_spring_security_check servlet. if you want to modify the behaviour, you should change the configuration or overwrite some services using DI. See here http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/files/1090/hacking_london.pdf

Comment: I updated my post above. There is my success and logout action. 1. What do I have to change in order to set the remember me cookie? 2. What do I have to do in order to get the auth action being displayed as a popup? Thank you for your help.